# Is there any Scala DSL for GUI?

Tags: scala, user-interface, dsl

Is there any Scala DSL for GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Scala comes with a swing wrapper dsl, you can find it in the `scala.swing` package.

Comment: Hello @gerferra , why do you consider `scala-swing` as a `DSL`? Iam just curious.

Answer (score 1):

[XScalaWT](http://bitbucket.org/djo/xscalawt/) is quite nice. I am currently using it for a project.